# Android Studio 3.1 cannot resolve symbol theme

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I just updated my Android studio to 3.1 and regret doing it it's wasting my whole morning help me pls. I'm using Gradle version 4.4 Gradle plugin 3.1

Comment: Please provide error snapshot or description to know more about your exact issue

Comment: add more info about the error pls

Comment: Here the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc

Answer (score 4):

Well after invalidating, cleaning , rebuilding the only thing that worked for me was to go to project structure, project, change to the old Gradle plugin 3.0.1 and to the old Gradle version 4.1 pressed ok then went to project structure again and changed to Gradle plugin 3.1.0 and gradle version to 4.4, changing these numbers in the files never worked for me , only when I went to project structures solved my problem