# Android Studio 3.1 can not resolve "Theme.AppCompat" styles properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Last night, I upgrade my android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1, and rebuild my project, and I got the error as show below.

[image]

**CHECKED LIST:**

1. compileSdkVersion 27
2. buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
3. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
4. implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
5. implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1 Cannot Resolve Symbol (Themes, Widget, attr, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc)

Comment: @BooberBunz thanks for your quickly response, and I checked all comments and not worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc):

1. Close project.
2. Remove it from the projects list (left side in the default Android Studio window).
3. Open existing project -> choose the project folder.

Basically, close & re-open the project.. worked for me (after even invalidating cache didn't work).

Related issues from issuetracker: [77211616](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77211616), [77938563](https://issuetracker.google.com/77938563), [73536373](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73536373)

Answer (score 1):

Even though [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49549706/4253952) works, it's actually a hassle because the issue keeps on reoccurring, especially after I switch branches (for different development or code reviews). So, I read further and [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638518/4253952):

***Switch your support lib version*** - either to a newer ver (27.1.1 stable as of now), or to an older version & back to current.

It's an alternative and seems to work.

Related issues from issuetracker: [77211616](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77211616), [77938563](https://issuetracker.google.com/77938563), [73536373](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73536373)