# In android studio 3.1 stable gives error on Theme and ?attr/actionBarSize attribute?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1

In the styles.xml when picking out Theme from android it gives the error. I have attached a screenshot related to this.
[Error in styles.xml File screenshot. Please Click to look into it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62SfL.png)

Another problem was with actionBarSize. In layout file it gives error when getting actionBarSize from android itself. i have attched a screenshot related to this below.
[?attr/actionBarSize gives error. Please click on this link to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm5mJ.png)

I have also checked and searched for answers about this but couldn't find one that could solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1 Cannot Resolve Symbol (Themes, Widget, attr, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc)

Comment: @RapunzelVanWinkle Thanks but I tried the same but didn't worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

close project -> import gradle project.

It's a stupid solution but somehow worked for me.

It's solution from other question btw, but i can't find it right now, Ill update if i find it.

**Update**
found it:
[Original issue with this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc)

**Update 2**
It addresses only issue with `?attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: Also with `?attr/colorBackgroundFloating`, `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and many more

Comment: Yeah i meant that `?attr/<name>` in general.

Comment: Thanks btw close `project -> Import project` worked for me. Even for `?attr/actionBarSize`