# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android-studio

After upgrading android studio to 3.1, in old projects I have a problem - 
[Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqRvc.jpg)

**Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' Validates resource references inside Android XML files**

I tried to do a lot of things but I still see the same problem.
What I've done: *sync project with gradle files; *invalidate cache and restart; *Bild, Rebild project; *compared gradle version in AS (4.4 - 3.1.0) and in a project (3.1.0) - the same; order of repositories google() jcenter()
and I did many other things but I don't have result(
who knows how to solve?

Comment: See also:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73536373

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jim Andreas. In your link I found another link that helped me! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523302/android-studio-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-themes-widget-attr-etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close the project from the File menu and open the project again as existing Android Studio project. This worked for me.