# Cannot resolve sysmbol 'GoogleApiAvailability' After upgrade android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have getting **Cannot resolve sysmbol 'GoogleApiAvailability'** after upgrad android studio 3.1.3 and upgrade gradle version 4.4.

Application gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
}
```

Why i am getting this error after update android studio 3.1.3?

Comment: What repositories have you configured for your project?

Comment: Having the same problem with play-services 15.0.1 and android studio 3.1.3
The app seems to compile with no issues though which is very strange

Comment: That is strange. You're getting this as an IDE warning (i.e. red squiggly lines) but not during compilation?

Comment: @ZhiQiao But gradle build on also showing error.

Comment: I am trying to delete old .android, .AndroidStudio and .gradle from user and open android studio again. Its resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

try to close the project, delete it from projects list then import it again through the import project option.

Take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49537464/3151549